# Question for school assignment to have python write to a file that does not exist

Tags: python

So I'm still learning python and have a school assignment where I need to write to a file that does not exist. I know I'm supposed to start with the line that I wrote as: out_file = open("rabbits.txt" , "w"), but that's where I'm lost. Shouldn't that make it so that the code that I wrote was written to the file "rabbits.txt" that I created? Am I putting that line of code in the wrong place? Because the txt file is just blank when I check it. Any pointers would help greatly.

```
out_file = open("rabbits.txt", "w")

month = 1
TOTAL_CAGES = 500

#Table Header
print("# Table of rabbit pairs\n")
print("{0:<4}{1:>5}{2:>5}{3:>5}".format("Month, ", "Adults, ", "Babies, ", "Total "))

#Variables
babies = 0
adults = 1

#Table Body
for month in range(1, 14 + 1):
    total = babies + adults
    print(f"{month}, {adults}, {babies}, {total}")
    babies = adults
    adults = total

#When cages will run out
while total > TOTAL_CAGES:
    print(f"# Cages will run out in month {month}")
    return
    
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open and close the file, but in the meantime you don't do anything with it. Once you get `out_file` variable, you can use `out_file.write(...)` instead of `print(...)`

Comment: Oh okay. So all of that code is a table that I have to make and that's why I have the prints in there. How would I put all of that code inside out_file.write()? Would I do out_file.write("") with quotes to include all of the code.

Comment: Or should I just replace the prints with out_file.write()?

Comment: just replace `print` with `out_file.write`, the content stays the same